# windows smart screen , when users running my installer That was Create using wix toolset

Tags: installation, wix, warnings, windows, sign

I had created an installer to my C# windows application using **Wix toolset** ,
This installer register some keys in the registry of windows while it is installing the App.

I had delivered it to the customers , but they feed me back that when they double click the .msi file it gives them the following warning by windows.[Windows smart screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyi6p.png)

What to do prevent this from being displayed to users as it give bad indication.